# Move binding source with bound controls

Tags: c#, winforms

In my form I bind text box controls to the binding source `_bsItmes` as

```
txtId.DataBindings.Add("Text", _bsItmes , "Id");   
txtName.DataBindings.Add("Text", _bsItmes , "Name");
```

When form loads it shows the data in the bindingsource correctly to the text boxes. But when I'm using `_bsItmes.MoveNext` , `MovePrevious`, `MoveLast`, `MoveFirst`, It doesn't update the text boxes values.

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Please tag with appropriate GUI tag. Is it winforms? ASP.NET Webforms? Or something else?